# Ionic 2: Handling android back button

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to handle my android back button in ionic 2 below is my code which will let the user to exit the app when they clicked from home page or login page

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Kmart',
            message: 'Do you want exit kmart app ?',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                  this.logger.info("cancel clicked")
                }
              },
              {
                text: 'ok',
                handler: () => {
                  this.platform.exitApp();
                }
              }
            ]
          });
          
       this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
          console.log('back button pressed')
          if (this.navCtrl.canGoBack()) {
            console.log('nav can go back')
            this.navCtrl.pop()
          } else {
            //here i have to show the alert for login and home page
            alert.present();
          } 
        }, 100);
```

The above piece of code is placed in my home.ts file

> i am not able to get the current page name so that i can make my app to exit.
>
> how to exit the app when user double click the app when he is on home or login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

[getActive()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#getActive) which returns the *ViewController* of current component check instance.
Use ViewChild to get navController in app.component.ts
Set `#mynav` in the template

template: `<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`

In component class:

```
@ViewChild('myNav') navCtrl: NavController
//to check the condition
let view = this.navCtrl.getActive();
if(view instanceof HomePage)
```

Check [ionic forum discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/get-current-page-view-name-in-rc0-returns-t/65905/7)

Comment: `EXCEPTION: No provider for t!` this error i am facing

Comment: getActive returns a viewController.. maybe try injecting viewcontroller in the constructor..

Comment: now i solved that issue but i have given the if condition that you have answered `if(this.navCtrl.getActive().component === HomePage)` inside my home.ts file  but it is working for login also is there any issue i have not mention loginpage how it is working

Comment: You mean HomePage condition is true for LoginPage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134744/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).

Comment: come to the discussion